# Configuring nginx to serve angular and node.js code with ssl and subdomain

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx, https

I am setting up an automated deployment of Angular & Node application. Here is what I have done so far:

1. Setup a node.js code pipeline on AWS code pipeline such that the artifact, a docker container is pushed to docker hub registry.
2. Another AWS code pipeline builds angular (frontend) and copies the static files in a S3 folder.
3. On an Azure/Ubuntu VM, I wrote a shell script that pulls the node image from docker hub (From step 1) and starts node.js (Backend application) container.
4. Another script builds and configures a container with nginx and UI with static files.

I am able to access the frontend with url : https://demo.example.com.
When I try to login (In which case the backend APIs get called), I get the error of Mixed Content error as the back-end is still running on HTTP.

I want to configure nginx such that I am able to access frontend and backend with HTTPS and with subdomains like : https://demo.example.com & https://demo-api.example.com. Most of the solutions around are based on docker-compose which I don't want to use.

My Nginx config file is:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

# Change the default configuration to enable ssl
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
    server_name example.com
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

My Dockerfile for frontend is:

```
azure@tracechain-vm:~$ cat Dockerfile
FROM nginx:latest

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY nginx-selfsigned.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY nginx-selfsigned.key /etc/ssl/private/
COPY ui-files/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```